# How to build multiple APKs from a single source project

Tags: android, gradle

I wanna get multiple APKs from a single source project.
Just the application's title, icon, and package name are different with the others.

The project is on gradle(1.12), as below.

```
.
└── my_project
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── settings.gradle
    └── module
        ├── build.gradle
        └── src
```

How can I do that?

Comment: have a look at flavours, like in this tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JDEK4wkN5I

Answer (score 2):

You can use [productFlavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) for that, and the under the promo and full folders (for example) create strings file (promo/res/values/strings.xml) with the update title value, same approach goes for the icon.

```
productFlavors {

    promo {
        packageName "com.woony.promo"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "v1.0.0_promo"
    }

    full {
        packageName "com.woony"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "v1.0.0"
    }

}
```

The updated project structure should be like the following

```
.
└── my_project
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── settings.gradle
    └── module
        ├── build.gradle
        └── src
            ├── main
            ├── promo
            └── full
```

And to generate the release apks just call the following once (just make sure you added [signingConfigs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations) and linked it in your release buildTypes)

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

- All the common files like java code, manifest and base resources are under ***"src/main"***
- Move your applications specific folders into ***"src/projects"***
- declare two productFlavor (one per applications) specifying ***applicationId*** and ***versionName***
- create two sourceSet (one per project) indicating the specific res, java, etc.. folders (i just needed res folder)

[image]

Full project's structure

[image]

Now, use **Build Variants** (bottom-left of Android Studio) to select the application to run

[image]